# Как в React создать текст, бегущий по кривой линии?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

[image: Что-то типа такого]

Она должна двигаться. По такой кривой линии. Пытался крутить что-нибудь с svg, с текстом работает. Но не могу добавить логотипы. Может кто сталкивался с таким. Либа какая есть для этого. Спасибо

Comment: лично я бы смотрел в сторону свойства shape-outside и дальше что-то придумал c js но точно не могу сказать нет времени на реализацию может у вас есть какие-то наброски как вы себе это представляли?

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью использования библиотеки `GSAP` и плагина `MotionPathPlugin`.

1. Установить [gsap](https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Installation?tab=yarn&module=esm&method=private%20registry&tier=free&club=false&require=false&trial=true)
2. Импортировать `import { gsap } from 'gsap'; import MotionPathPlugin from 'gsap/MotionPathPlugin';`
3. Настроить.

Ниже мой пример. Но можно почитать. Настроек много. Можно выбрать для себя все что необходимо.

```
gsap.registerPlugin(MotionPathPlugin);
const tl = gsap.timeline({
    defaults: {
        duration: 1,
        ease: 'none',
        repeat: -1,
        repeatDelay: 6,
        autoRemoveChildren: true,
    },
});
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    tl.to('#curverText0', {
        duration: 15,
        motionPath: {
            path: '#curve',
            align: '#curve',
            autoRotate: true,
            alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
        },
    })
        .to('#curverText1', {
            duration: 15,
            delay: -14,
            motionPath: {
                path: '#curve',
                align: '#curve',
                autoRotate: true,
                alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
            },
        })
        .to('#curverText2', {
            duration: 15,
            delay: -14,
            motionPath: {
                path: '#curve',
                align: '#curve',
                autoRotate: true,
                alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
            },
        })
        .to('#curverText3', {
            duration: 15,
            delay: -14,
            motionPath: {
                path: '#curve',
                align: '#curve',
                autoRotate: true,
                alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
            },
        })
        .to('#curverText4', {
            duration: 15,
            delay: -14,
            motionPath: {
                path: '#curve',
                align: '#curve',
                autoRotate: true,
                alignOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
            },
        })
```

В качестве path: '#curve' использовал svg кривую.

```
<svg
            width="1572"
            height="764"
            viewBox="0 0 1572 764"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
            <path
                id="curve"
                d="M1.0897 763.494C57.6942 715.299 294.24 504.092 578.043 538.445C758.246 560.257 1099.43 487.283 1113.91 262.345C1128.39 37.4069 1408.87 0.0568685 1571.17 0.940575"
                stroke="white"
            />
        </svg>
        <div id="curverText" className={styles.curverText}>
            {STACK_ELEMENT.map(({ title, src, width, height }, idx) => (
                <div id={`curverText${idx}`} className={styles.curverTextItem} key={title}>
                    {src !== '' && (
                        <Image src={src} alt={title} width={width} height={height} />
                    )}
                    {title}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

[image: Готово!]